# I found the IP Addresses via Logs & Google AP. I have a question about the the GPI?

Tags: ip

I found out how to get all the IP addresses via Server Logs.

I'm using the IP addresses to get the Latitude and Longitude. The address appear to be approx 1 3 miles away from the actual address of the vistor.

Can someone explain why the GPI coordinates via IP address are not exactly matching the location of the user?

Is there a more dependable way to get the address?

Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar question answered [here](http://whatismyipaddress.com/geolocation-accuracy):

> Determining the nation of an Internet user based on his or her IP address is relatively simple and accurate (95%-99% percent) because a country name is required information when an IP range is allocated and IP registrars supply that information for free.
>   Determining the physical location down to a city or ZIP code, however, is more difficult and less accurate because there is no official source for the information, users sometimes share IP addresses and Internet service providers often base IP addresses in a city where the company is basing operations.

Unfortunately, it's generally impossible to get the exact location of an user based on their IP address – only approximations.

Comment: Explain to me what the Longitude and Latitude represents?

Comment: Coordinates? Did you not learn that in school? Check wikipedia. They are a coordinate system indicating a position on the globe - you know, that little ball called earth ;)

Answer (score 1):

An IP address is not tied to a location, and any data you can get will always be an approximation.

Comment: Explain to me what the Longitude and Latitude represents?

Answer (score 0):

The only tie between and individual IP address and geographic location is the admin/billing/technical address associated in WHOIS with the IP address or IP range in question.

The location computed is only as good as the address information provided and only as good as the mapping of address to grid system coordinates.

Further, for an IP address assigned to, say, IBM, WHOIS might well report an address of   Armonk, NY USA. IBM has sites and operations around the world. If the computer assigned that IP address happens to be located in, say, San Francisco,...

I believe that at least some geolocation software also looks at routing tables to try and figure out what the physical connectivity of an IP address is, to help triangulate the location. If our hypothetical IBM server in San Francisco is routed through adjacent ATT hubs in the Bay area, then, its a reasonable supposition that the box is not actually in Armonk.